# Merge functions with 2 non-overlapping sets of parameters in a pythonic way

Tags: python, api, parameters

I parse abstract syntax trees in Python. For this, I have designed a custom tree structure & an interface to operate on it. Among others, I offer 2 different search functions:

```
def findNode(self, start, name)
```

&

```
def findNodeByLineno(node, lineno, prevNode, nodeType=None)
```

The first function searches for a node given name, the latter one compares line numbers & node's type, if given.
My subconsciousness tells me that this a leaky interface design, but I cannot come up with a decision how to merge these two functions in one common function.

```
def findNode(self, start, name, lineno, prevNode, nodeType)
```

is in my opinion also wrong, because it does not make clear that the set of parameters can be split only in two groups. A user cannot search for a node based only on prevNode or on nodeType alone. Having two different functions seems like a very C-like solution.

Is there a pythonic way to solve this design conflict?

Comment: you can accept two tuples or two dict for example

Comment: Your subconscious is not correct this time. It's perfectly fine to have the two functions there, as they **are** performing different functions. Why do you want to combine them, and then later in the function definition you will need to do `if`s to decide what to do with the parameters?

Comment: @justhalf because they sort of do the same thing. they search for a node given some criteria and return it if it has been found. it's just that the criteria are different, the result and the general idea are the same.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me that these are mutually exclusive options. Why limit the arguments to be only useful in groups? I would imagine that one findNode with keyword arguments would solve the problem well, and I would expect as a user of these functions that supplying all the arguments would result in a list of nodes that satisfy all the criteria.

Comment: @PavloDyban: I understand your concern, but I think in this case your design of having two functions is already good. Even if you want to have a function that capture the "general search", you will still need the two functions. Consider the case when you have the third general function. Inside that function (say `findNodeComplete`), you will parse the argument, then based on what the user wants, it will call `findNode` if it's search by name, or `findNodeByLineno` if it's search by line numbers. That unnecessarily makes the problem harder, since calling different functions are already clear.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon this would be an overkill for the parser I am building right now, but might be a sensible solution in the future. At the moment, the application of `findNode()` is to return 1 specific node, not a list.

Comment: You might be able to make a `findNodePredicate` that takes a predicate function (which can return a direction to search if needed) and your two functions can be shallow wrappers for `findNodePredicate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think having those two functions is terribly bad, but it may be possible to just drop altogether, i.e. there's nothing to merge.

The idea is that you can factor out the code which traverses the syntax tree into a `findNodeBy` function. The function takes a predicate and it returns the first node for which the given predicate returns `True`.

I don't quite understand the meaning of the variables given to your `findNodeByLineNo` function, but using `findNodeBy` you could implement (or replace) your `findNode` with:

```
def findNode(start, name):
    return findNodeBy(start, lambda n: n.name == name)
```

You may find that those convenience functions have so little "meat" to them that you may just as well drop them altogether and use plain "findNodeBy" calls throughout your code.

Now (this part doesn't quite affect your question) you may then find that you could replace `findNodeBy` as well if you treat your syntax tree as an iterable and then use things like `itertools.dropwhile` to find a specific element matching a predicate. Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to solve this is to use a simple wrapper function with optional arguments.

```
def findNode(start, name):
    pass


def findNodeByLineno(node, lineno, prevNode, nodeType=None):
    pass


def find_node(start=None, name=None, node=None, lineno=None, prevNode=None, nodeType=None):
    if start is not None and name is not None:
            return findNode(start, name)
    else:
        try:
            return findNodeByLineno(node, lineno, prevNode, nodeType)
        except TypeError:
            print("Improper arguments")
```

---

### Console Session

```
>>> from wrapper import find_node
>>> find_node(start="Cheese", name="Cookie")
findNode was called
>>> find_node(node="Cheese", lineno=21, prevNode="Happy", nodeType="Cheese")
findNodeByLineno was called
```